# Selenium, загрузка страницы с большим количеством JavaScript

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день. Я пишу парсер HTML-страницы на Selenium. Чтоб получить страницу, в сервис нужно сначала залогиниться. Страница логина содержит огромное количество JavaScript, который сначала выполняется, а потом пользователю показывается уже "отрисованная" страница.

Когда я отрабатывала маневры залогинивания с имеющим интерфейс ChromeDriver-ом, все было прекрасно, на странице присутствовали элементы ввода логина и пароля, WebDriver их успешно находил, засылал значения, кликал кнопку и вуаля. Но для "боевой" реализации мне нужно безинтерфейсное решение. Я рассчитывала на SimpleBrowserDriver, но в нем почему-то при той же последовательности действий не выполняется JavaScript. Страничка через SimpleBrowserDriver после

```
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://address.com/login/");
```

получается такая же, как в обычном браузере при отключенном JavaScript, и нужных полей в ней нет. Можно ли как-то "пропинать" изнутри SimpleBrowserDriver, вызвать какие-то события, чтоб он сначала выполнил весь JavaScript, а потом уже вернул мне страницу? Нашла информацию про JavascriptExecutor, но мне надо не свои скрипты выполнять на запрашиваемой странице, а скрипты самой страницы.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону PhantomJS. В своё время использовал его для этих целей, правда, из Java.
P.S. Прошу прощения, не сразу увидел Ваш комментарий под ответом. Вот и хорошо, что всё получилось :)

Comment: Спасибо! PhantomJS хотя бы показывает нужные поля. Правда,  тоже не без багов - похоже, пытается выполнять мой код быстрее, чем у него загружаются нужные данные, так что  придется его какими-то хендлерами обвешивать (потому что ставить sleep и надеяться, что мы всё успели,  как-то неправильно) и ловить события. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Natalia, попробуйте поставить ожидание загрузки нужного Вам элемента. Пример вроде есть вот здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374382/how-to-wait-for-element-to-load-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `SimpleBrowser` отсутствует поддержка `JavaScript`, ищите другие пути решения

> No javascript though, but frankly, if you need javascript support,
>   you'll lose most of the performance gain of a headless browser anyway
>   (because of all the extra requests you'll have to do).

Источник: [GitHub SimpleBrowser WebDriver](https://github.com/SimpleBrowserDotNet/SimpleBrowser.WebDriver)

Comment: Спасибо.  Подключила PhantomJS, он вроде смог загрузить всё как надо.